# How to request permission to send notifications Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

How do I create a pop-up window when launching an application with notification permission? In Android 13, this is mandatory. The permissions are already in the manifest. I need to somehow embed a permission request into this code, I do not know how to do it. Help please
This is my class with notifications:

```
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val TAG = "Notifi"
    private var cityName: String = ""
    private var location: String = ""

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        cityName = intent.getStringExtra("CITY_KEY").toString()
        location = intent.getStringExtra("LOCATION_KEY").toString()
        sendNotification(context)
    }

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun sendNotification(context: Context) {
        val mainActivityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        mainActivityIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        // Создайте канал уведомления для Android Oreo и выше
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "NotificationChannelName"
            val descriptionText = "NotificationChannelDescription"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            Log.d(TAG, "Step 1")
        }

        val expandedView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.notification_expanded)


        Log.d(TAG, "Сообщение отправилось")

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val dataForNotifi = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    fetchWeatherData(0, cityName, location)
                }

                val collapsedView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_collapsed_notification)
                collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text1, dataForNotifi.pushCurrentTemp)
                collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text2, dataForNotifi.pushMaxMin)
                // Установите ресурсы изображений для ImageView
                collapsedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_icon, R.drawable.ic_app_push)
                collapsedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_icon2, dataForNotifi.pushCurrentImage)

                // Создайте уведомление
                val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_push)
                    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                    .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) // <- добавьте PendingIntent к сборщику уведомлений (NotificationCompat.Builder)
                    .setAutoCancel(true) // <- это остановит уведомление после нажатия на него

                val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, builder.build())

                val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
                val dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
                val timeFormatted = dateFormat.format(currentTime)

                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_address, dataForNotifi.pushAddress)
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_time, timeFormatted)
                expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.push_current_image, dataForNotifi.pushCurrentImage)
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_current_temp, dataForNotifi.pushCurrentTemp)

                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_firstcase_day, dataForNotifi.pushFirstCaseDay)
                expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.push_firstcase_image, dataForNotifi.pushFirstCaseImage)
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_firstcase_temp, dataForNotifi.pushFirstCaseTemp)

                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_secondcase_day, dataForNotifi.pushSecondCaseDay)
                expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.push_secondcase_image, dataForNotifi.pushSecondCaseImage)
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_secondcase_temp, dataForNotifi.pushSecondCaseTemp)

                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_thirdcase_day, dataForNotifi.pushThirdCaseDay)
                expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.push_thirdcase_image, dataForNotifi.pushThirdCaseImage)
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_thirdcase_temp, dataForNotifi.pushThirdCaseTemp)

                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_fourthcase_day, dataForNotifi.pushFourthCaseDay)
                expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.push_fourthcase_image, dataForNotifi.pushFourthCaseImage)
                expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.push_fourthcase_temp, dataForNotifi.pushFourthCaseTemp)

                // Обновите уведомление
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, builder.build())

                Log.d(TAG, "Сообщение обновилось")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Обработка ошибок
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: ${e.message}", e)
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun fetchWeatherData(position: Int, cityName: String, userLocation: String): DataForNotifi {
        val weather = Weather()
        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
            weather.getWeatherData(position, cityName, userLocation) { _, _, _, dataForNotifi ->
                continuation.resume(dataForNotifi)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the activity:

```
private fun setupNotificationAlarm() {
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("CITY_KEY", city)
        intent.putExtra("LOCATION_KEY", coordinates)
        
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        
        val intervalInMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)

        alarmManager.setExact(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + intervalInMillis,
            pendingIntent
        )
    }

    private fun requestExactAlarmPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

            if (!alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM).apply {data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                }
                val requestCode = 0
                startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android 13 you have to request the notification permission manually. First of all check the build version if build version is below 13 then you don't need to ask for permission else use below code:

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
           // Do your task on permission granted
        } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
            // TODO: display an educational UI explaining to the user the features that will be enabled
            //       by them granting the POST_NOTIFICATION permission. This UI should provide the user
            //       "OK" and "No thanks" buttons. If the user selects "OK," directly request the permission.
            //       If the user selects "No thanks," allow the user to continue without notifications.
        } else {
            // Directly ask for the permission
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
    }
    else{
        // Below Android 13 You don't need to ask for notification permission.
    }
```

Create permission activity result method like this so that you can get the requested permission is granted on not.

```
private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
) { isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // Permission Granted
    } else {
        // Permission Denied / Cancel
    }
}
```